# ControlsFX - Exception in thread "ControlsFX Error: ControlsFX 8.40.10 requires at least Java Version 8 Update 40

Tags: java, controlsfx

I've looked at other issues similar. What I can tell you is:
This program worked a week ago.
I haven't changed scenebuilder.
A new JRE, as I recall, was downloaded and it is 1.8.0_101-b13.
This is on Linux 64bit.
In the very same program Lambda notifications still work.
I did just upgrade scenebuilder to 8.2.0 from 8.0.0. But I am not actively working on a fxml file.

I believe the only change was a recent upgrade on the JDK/JRE. The default computer is the same release as the default runtime.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I could have sworn another issue on this was resolved by changing the version of scenebuilder...which did not, on the surface, make sense. Although there was a new SceneBuilder out there from Gluon.

This problem is fixed by upgrading ControlsFX to version 8.40.11, up from 8.40.10.

Answer (score 0):

This [issue](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/issues/675/jdk-180_101-180_40) was resolved on 13 April 2016 for ControlsFX **8.40.x**, but ControlsFX **8.20.x** still has this problem (8.20.9 was released on 2 June 2015).

To fix the problem:

- use ControlsFX **8.40.x** or higher, or
- use a Java version that has a two-digit minor version number (both 8u**20** and 8u**40** will be fine).

What is the bug? Well, ControlsFX is comparing the minor versions of Java and ControlsFX as `String` values: "40" is considered higher than "101" because the first character "4" is higher than "1" ([source](https://bitbucket.org/controlsfx/controlsfx/src/56a1e8ebdde0a28275dce46666288c72e7963312/controlsfx/src/main/java/impl/org/controlsfx/version/VersionChecker.java?at=default&fileviewer=file-view-default#VersionChecker.java-90)). The implemented fix parses the version strings as `Integer` values.